# How can detect text file line breaks in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a txt file that created in notepad , containing these lines for example :

```
lao_esan_ubon_444
chantrick
solikh
knalpoot
tanduy_007
Mario3010
```

Now i need to put every line in an array cell , like these:

```
array('lao_esan_ubon_444','chantrick','solikh','knalpoot','tanduy_007','Mario3010');
```

How can i do this with PHP (for long lists)?

Comment: Mark: The `file` function combines both of these.

Comment: Didn't realize that about the `file` function. Splendid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`file` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

```
$array = file('somefile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Note that the `flags` parameter (`FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`) is only available in PHP 5 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$data=file_get_contents("your file name");
$array=explode("\n",$data);
?>
```

hope this helps